# why has an empty array in react native no length attribute?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, native

In a render method of a component, i want to check the length of an array. When i log the array its self, the console writes

```
console.log("in render: ",this.props.details);
output: in render: Array []
```

When I log the length of the same array, I get an error:

```
console.log("in render: ",this.props.details.length);
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.details.length')
```

Normally, length should return "0" in this case.
Are arrays specifically treated in react?

Thanks.

Comment: Try adding both logs `console.log("in render: ",this.props.details); console.log("in render: ",this.props.details.length);` I'm sure you'll get that `details` is not defined for whatever reason. For example if you add `this.props.details` asynchronously.

Comment: It seems to be Async. It is bad design, when I get a type of Array but not its length. It should be type of AsyncArray, Promise ... something that clearly explains what I'm dealing with.

Comment: " when I get a type of Array but not its length" you are not getting an array. The error messages says that `this.props.details` is undefined when your code tries to read it's length. If you did both logs you likely saw that it was undefined. It is hard to say more w/o seeing your actual code that sets `details` property of the component and the component code itself.

Comment: Console said, that I getting an array.

Comment: Sorry, but this is just impossible :) If you do have an array you wont get an error reading it's length. Error message clearly states that when you reading length you **do not have an array yet**.

Comment: `this.props.details` is an result of axios middleware for redux. I called

Comment: Further chatting makes no sense, unless you provide [Minimal Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue. As I have already wrote the error clearly shows you do not have an array yet when reading the length.